# Can a user open a text file inside jar and make changes in it?

Tags: java, file, text, jar

I need to put a text file inside jar. When user runs the jar a login screen will appear. Once he logs in and authenticates himself, only then a text file should appear and he should be able to write in it and save it. I am done with the login and authentication part, can any one help me with coding for only the part where text file is opened and user has access to write in it and save it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, however do NOT modify the file directly. If writing the modified contents fail for some reason, you lose both the original file *and* the modified file.

Create a temporary file in which you put the modified contents, and only then replace the original.

Example:

```
final Map<String, String> = Collections.emptyMap();
final URI zip = URI.create("jar:file:/path/to/your/jar");
final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip, env);

final Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("tmp", "txt");
final Path srcfile = zipfs.getPath("path/of/file/into/jar");
final Path renamed = srcfile.resolveSibling("newfile");

// read contents of source file, for instance Files.newBufferedReader(), or
// Files.readAllLines(); then write the modified content into tempFile; and
// when done:

Files.copy(tempFile, renamed);
Files.delete(tempFile);
Files.move(renamed, srcfile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

zipfs.close(); // <-- don't forget that
```

Note how the renaming to the original file is the *very last* operation.

Comment: I am making a logging program that logs the changes. My flow is authentication--> file opens--> changes done--> changes made are saved in new file--> new file is sent to the uploader. 

Can we do like this. Like once the authentication is done, jar will fully extract the file in a location and start monitoring file in that location?

Comment: There is a `WatchService` in Java 7 so yes you can monitor. But this is not really your original question...

Comment: yes you said like we shouldn't directly play with a file inside jar so i thought this can be another option.

Comment: This is a general advice, not only for jars; when you have to modify the contents of the file you should never modify the file directly. Again, if write fails you lose the file. But why would you want to monitor the changes? It is your application which will write the changes anyway, right?

Comment: The changes made to text file say 1.txt will be written into a new file say 2.txt and this 2.txt will be mailed to the original creator of 1.txt so that he knows what is being done with his file. Can you please send me a mail at vishukamble@engineer.com , if that's not a problem!